# Check input for format and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to check, if the content of an input field match to a given format like 'd (d-d)' and the values are correct

Valid inputs would be:

```
13 (11-14)
13 (13-13)
```

The values in the bracket gives a range, so

1. the first value in the range should be lower or equal the second value
2. the value before the bracket is equal to the first and second value or it is IN the range

My attempt:

```
$subject = "3 (1-4)";
$pattern = '/^([0-9])\(([0-9]\-[0-9]?)\)$/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$first = $matches[1][0];
$second = $matches[2][0];

// check if first <= second...
```

But there are a lot of mistakes.

Comment: regex for arithmetic??????

Comment: regex for checking the format... Open minded for a complete different solution...

Comment: You tagged this as JavaScript and jQuery while it is clearly PHP...

Comment: Originally I need JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function check($subject) {
    $pattern = '/^(\d+)\s\((\d+)\-(\d+)\)$/';
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

    $value = (int)$matches[1];
    $min   = (int)$matches[2];
    $max   = (int)$matches[3];

    return $value >= $min && $value <= $max; 
}

print check("3 (1-4)") ? 'true' : 'false'; // prints true
print check("2 (3-7)") ? 'true' : 'false'; // prints false
```

Comment: Sometimes I have to check for decimals and sometimes only for integer values. Do you have an idea how to realize that?